# Asp.net MVC log4net with lockingModel makes session lost

Tags: asp.net-mvc, log4net

I get a MVC website and with the log4net to record the log.

In the web application, I store the user information in session, add log some information after executing one operation. Then the session lost when I returned to the home page(just type the url of the home page).

I am sure that the session lost which has no relation to the "Response.Redirect()" or something else, because I test the application and found it will recover after I comment the lockingModel property which value is "log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock" in log4net config file.

Below is the configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<log4net debug="true">
    <appender name="AllInfoRollingAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
        <file value="bin\\Log\\AllInfo-UniqueBlog-" />
        <lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock" />
        <appendToFile value="true" />
        <staticLogFileName value="false" />
        <rollingStyle value="Composite" />
        <datePattern value="yyyy-MM-dd.LOG" />
        <maximumFileSize value="1M" />
        <maxSizeRollBackups value="4" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
            <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger: %message%newline%exception" />
        </layout>
    </appender>
    <root>
        <level value="ALL" />
        <appender-ref ref="AllInfoRollingAppender" />
    </root>
</log4net>
```

So I think the "lockingModel" property in log4net config cause this error, but i don't know the reason, and it will not throw any error there, does anyone encounter this? I found it is inconceivable because this shouldn't cause this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is totally not readable. However I have to things you can check. If your session is lost, do you log before or after the Session.Redirec(). If you log after the session redirect, your code is never hit. The redirect ends your current thread. Next thing you can enable log4net debugging:

```
<configuration>
   <appSettings>
      <add key="log4net.Internal.Debug" value="true"/>
   </appSettings>
...
<system.diagnostics>
    <trace autoflush="true">
        <listeners>
            <add 
                name="textWriterTraceListener" 
                type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener" 
                initializeData="C:\tmp\log4net.txt" />
        </listeners>
    </trace>
</system.diagnostics>
  ...
</configuration>
```

If something bad happens in log4net, you will see it in the logs.